# Meaning of curly brackets in email template

Tags: html, css, email-templates

So, I am working on a html email template and I see this code.

What does it mean when it says:

```
 <div style='{{container}}'></div>
```

what do the two curly brackets within the style tag indicate?

Comment: Where is the code?? and { } these are scopes who contain the rule/command for their parent/class/id.

Comment: sorry didnt realize that if you put < it removes it. also was wondering when designing a email template its best not to have div tag so should i change those div tags to span tags.

Answer (score 1):

its angular.js code

angular.js uses {{ }} to bind variables to HTML,

in your condition, the CSS style class name is stored in the variable "container" and then used in the code
This way the application programmer can change the style class of the div from JAVASCRIPT easily based on different conditions

if you don't need dynamic styles, just remove the {{container}} part and replace it with the CSS style class name you have

static version will be somthing like this:

```
<div style='myCLassName'> .... </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you work on laravel views. So in blade {{ }} means < ?php ?>
In this case it was set "container" in controller and was passed to view as variable.